# Berkeley DB: How to GET a specific KEY from QUEUE

Tags: berkeley-db

I am writing some fixed length records to a QUEUE in Berkeley DB, and get back the record number agter each PUT. So for example if I put 4 messages on the queue I am getting back 1, 2, 3, 4.

NOw I would like to retrieve a message from the queue based on it's KEY....

So if I try:

```
db_recno_t keyval;   
DBT key, data; 

memset(&key, 0, sizeof(DBT)); 
memset(&data, 0, sizeof(DBT)); 

keyval = 2;
key.data =  &keyval; 
key.ulen = sizeof(keyval);
ret = q->get(q, NULL, &key, &data, DB_CONSUME);
printf("Key peek = %i\n", keyval);
printf("Data peek = %s\n", data.data);
```

I keep getting back the first record in the queue, not the one I specify with the key (in this case "2")

I know the keys are 1,2,3,4 on the queue so I am wondering what stupid thing I am doing here?

Thanks for the help, much aprreciated ;-)

Lynton

Answer (score 0):

Try some other database format than DB_QUEUE if you need random access.